# Хостинг для базы данных MySQL

Tags: mysql

для небольшого учебного проекта мне желательно разместить БД на каком-нибудь хосте. Я попробовал несколько бесплатных хостингов, но все они предоставляют локалхосты для сайтов. Возможно ли вообще закинуть БД  на какой-нибудь хостинг и управлять ей из созданного приложения? Очень желательно что-бы бесплатно, размер дискового пространства особого значения не имеет.

Comment: https://ru.000webhost.com/besplatniy-mysql-hosting

Comment: я бы советовал бы купить Вам дешевый ( по отзывам посмотреть). Меньше времени потратите на все, да и стоит он как 1-2 чашки кофе. Например - https://jino.ru/hosting/price/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Бесплатно можно сделать из своего домашнего компьютера хостинг. Если нужно, чтобы люди могли из интернета получить доступ к этой бд, надо будет [открыть порты](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3096j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Чтобы каждый раз не скидывать свой новый IP, можно купить белый IP *(всегда одинаковый, стоит копейки, около 150р в год если не путаю)*. По мне так самый удобный вариант.